# What is an eliminator?

Tags: eliminator, terminology

What is an eliminator?

- Are there any differences between an eliminator and an *elimination form* (such as $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ for binary products)?
- Does every type have exactly one?
- Is the type of the eliminator completely determined by the types of the constructors?

The motivation for this question is: I'm trying to understand a $\Pi$-type definition of $\mathbb{N}$ quoted from [an answer on this site](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/327).

The definition, with the notation changed only slightly, is given below.

$$ \mathbb{N} \;\;{\small\text{is defined as}}\;\; \bigg(\Pi (N : *) \mathop. \Pi (A : *) \mathop. A \to (N \to A \to A) \to (N \to A)\bigg) : * $$

According to the body of the answer, $A \to (N \to A \to A) \to (N \to A)$ is the type of the eliminator of the natural numbers.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm wondering what an eliminator is and how they are used. They seem a bit different from an *elimination form* but have a family resemblance with it and an elimination rule. The definition of the natural numbers is from another answer ... so I know it contains an actual eliminator. I'm wondering if my guess as to *why* it's an eliminator is correct. Every part of this question except the title is my attempt to show my work and make sense of an example I've been given.

Comment: The definition of $f$ is not correct (it loops). You need two cases: $f(x, g, 0) = x$ and $f(x, g S(n)) = g(x, g, f(x, g, n))$. The function $f$ is realizes primitive recursion, and is the proof relevant counter-part of induction. I don't understand what you're asking, by the way.

Comment: I should point out that the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ given is *not* complete. It is insufficient for showing that $\mathbb{N}$ has the desired properties. You need something else in addition, such as parametricity.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you for the explanation. I'll rewrite the question in the morning and cut out the guesswork, although I don't completely get why it isn't the case that all eliminations are proof-irrelevant. Also thanks for the correction to $f$ ... somehow I had gotten in my head that because the $N$ in the definition was ranging over all types in $*$, that meant that I couldn't use $S$ or $0$ in $f$.

Comment: I misspoke: eliminators are proof *relevant* eliminations. Regarding $S$ and $0$, of course you need to define them as suitable $\lambda$-terms. And the recursor can also be similarly defined using just $\lambda$-terms.

Comment: A constructor for X is a way of making things of type X, and an eliminator for X is a way of using things of type X to make other stuff (i.e. a way to make functions from X to other types). Is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I rewrote the question and [posted a meta question here](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91/good-what-is-an-x-questions-good-answers-to-them). Please don't delete the comments just yet, I may rewrite the question again based on people's feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role of constructors and eliminators can be understood through category theory. For every type former (for example $A\times B$, $A+B$, $A^B$, $\mathbb N$, etc...) we can ask

- How can we construct a morphism *into* this type?
- How can we construct a morphism *out* of this type?

We might as well call the morphisms into the type *constructors* and morphisms out of the type as *eliminators*.

The product type, for example, has the following universal property:

> Given $P,Q$, there exists morphisms $\pi_1 : P\times Q\to P$, $\pi_2 : P\times Q\to Q$, such that for every object $R$, and morphisms $p : R\to P$, $q:R\to Q$ such that $\pi_1\circ p = \pi_2\circ q$, there exists a unique morphism $\langle p,q\rangle : R\to P\times Q$ such that $\langle p,q\rangle\circ \pi_1 = p$ and $\langle p,q\rangle\circ\pi_2 = q$.

From this, we see that the eliminators are
$$\pi_1 : P\times Q\to P\\\pi_2 : P\times Q\to Q$$ and the only constructor is
$$\frac{p : R\to P\quad q : R\to Q}{\langle p,q\rangle : R\to P\times Q}.$$

Similarly, the [universal property of the natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers_object) gives constructors
$$z : 1\to \mathbb N\\
s : \mathbb N\to \mathbb N$$
and eliminators
$$\frac{q : 1\to A\quad f : A\to A}{\text{rec}(q,f) : \mathbb N\to A}$$

Note that this is slightly different from require $f : \mathbb N\to A\to A$, but this is an equivalent, and often more convenient presentation.

So there is no reason why we can't have more than one eliminator, or that constructors/eliminators can't be more complicated. As a final example, [function types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object) have constructor
$$\frac{f : A\to B}{\lambda f : B^A}$$
and eliminator
$$\text{eval} : B^A\times A\to B,$$
where the only way to eliminate something of type $B^A$ is to pair it with something of type $A$.

---

It's also interesting to note that $\mathbb N$ belongs to a class of inductive types, which means the eliminator has a specific form.
$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
Indeed, for an inductive type defined by an endofunctor $F:\mc C\to\mc C$ (where $\mc C$ is the category of types) (in the case of $\mathbb N$, $F(X) := X\times (X\to X)$), the inductive type is defined to be the [initial algebra for $F$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor). If $A$ is initial for $F$, this briefly means that for every other type $X$, there is a unique map of algebras $F(A)\to F(X)$. This map is the eliminator for $A$.

Comment: How does this fit with the picture where product types have only one eliminator (of type $(P \to Q \to R) \to P \times Q \to R$?

Comment: @JasonGross Should $R$ be universally quantified?

Comment: all type variables in eliminators are always universally quantified.  So, yes $R$ (and $P$ and $Q$) is universally quantified.

Comment: The two pictures corresponds to viewing the product type as positive or negative. In polarized notation we can write them as $\otimes$ and $\&$, respectively.

Comment: In linear logic they are not equivalent, but with weakening and contraction, they are, so we often confuse them.