# How do clausal definitions work?

Tags: type-theory, definition

I'm most familiar with the metatheory of calculi based around expressions.

But systems like Agda use separate clauses for definitions.

```
ifte : { A : Set } -> bool -> A -> A -> A
ifte true x y = x
ifte false x y = y
```

[Copatterns](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/copatterns.html) are a similar construct.

I'm mostly interested because I was interested in whether this sort of thing could simplify use of positive types.

For the STLC this sort of scheme suggests an almost ANFish sort of approach?

$$ \frac{x \colon \tau \in \Gamma}{\Gamma \vdash x \colon \tau}$$

$$\frac{ \begin{split}\Gamma, x\colon \tau_1 \vdash e_1 \colon \tau_2\\
\Gamma, y\colon \tau_1 \to \tau_2 \vdash e_2\colon \tau_3
\end{split}}{\Gamma \vdash \textbf{let} \, y \, x := e_1 \, \textbf{in} \, e_2 \colon \tau_3}$$

$$\frac{ \begin{split}\Gamma \vdash e_1 \colon \tau_1 \to \tau_2\\
\Gamma \vdash e_2 \colon \tau_1
\end{split}}{\Gamma \vdash e_1 e_2 \colon \tau_2}$$

I think for sum types you might have pattern matching like

$$\frac{ \begin{split}
\Gamma, x\colon \tau_1 \vdash e_1 \colon \tau_3\\
\Gamma , x\colon \tau_2 \vdash e_2 \colon \tau_3\\
\Gamma , y\colon \tau_1 + \tau_2 \to \tau_3 \vdash e_3 \colon \tau_4
\end{split}}{\Gamma \vdash \textbf{let} \, \begin{split}y \, x := e_1 \\
y \, x := e_2
\end{split} \, \textbf{in} \, e_3 \colon \tau_3}$$

I'm not really sure I'm getting the spirit of clausal definitions or how they might simplify things.

How precisely would you formalize these sort of clausal definitions?

Comment: I was reminded about clausal definitions [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/272/153)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in non-dependent languages then it is probably not a proof-assistants related question. Those are quite well-studied in computer science. So I assume you are asking about using clausal definitions in dependently typed languages, as opposed to using eliminators (the expression-based substitute for pattern matching and recursion etc).

You can read about these in a series of papers.

- It began with [Eliminating dependent pattern matching](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11780274_27). This translates clausal pattern matching into eliminators.
- Then it is improved to [without using axiom K](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/eliminating-dependent-pattern-matching-without-k/4BC4EA2D02D801E5ABED264FE5FB177A).
- Then copatterns are added [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3236770). And this paper also addresses other problems involving clausal definitions. Its emphasis is less on translating them to eliminators, as languages like Agda don't do the translation anyway.
- Another topic of relevance is termination checking, to which [foetus](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/foetus-Termination-Checker-for-Simple-Functional-Abel/c216d842401569de47d2472b84d33f4f38bbe670) is a good introduction. I'm not familiar with coinductive progress checking.

As for how it simplifies stuff, see if you can define `head : Vec (suc n) A -> A` that fetches the first element of a nonempty vector using eliminators only. (Hint: it's very long.) More in-depth discussion of this can be found at

- [The view from the Left](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/view-from-the-left/F8A44CAC27CCA178AF69DD84BC585A2D) which discusses techniques available with clausal definitions.